# TkTextに表示するテキストのコピーを禁止する方法

Tags: ruby

rubyのTkTextを使ってテキストを表示し、bindによりマウスの右クリックや移動をプログラムで使用しています。

このとき、マウスを使用したテキストのコピーを禁止できるでしょうか。
stateをdisabledに設定することによりテキストの編集を禁止できますが、テキストのコピーは可能です。

TkTextに表示するテキストのコピーを禁止する方法についてご教示願います。

Answer (score 1):

TkText の `exportselection` を `false` に設定してみてはどうですか。

```
require 'tk'

text = TkText.new('exportselection' => false)
text.pack('fill' => 'both')
quitbutton = TkButton.new(nil, 'text' => 'quit', 'command' => proc{ exit })
quitbutton.pack('fill' => 'both')

Tk.mainloop
```

ただ、`exportselection` は X Window System の selection を対象としていると説明されていますので、X Window System 以外のウィンドウシステムを採用している環境では期待通りに動作しないかもしれません。

Comment: exportselectionは試して上手くいきませんでした。おっしゃる通り、X windows 用と考えています。

Comment: @JIJI ソースコードを眺めてみると `TkSelection.handle(text, nil);` を実行することでコピー動作が行われなくなる様です。Linux + X Window ではその通りになりましたが、Windows や OS X ではどうなるか確認していただけますか。